# C# работа с bmp

Tags: c#, bmp, .net, изображения

Здравствуйте!
Открываю bmp файл.

```
image  = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(imagePath));
.......
//Затем изменяю цвет некоторых пикселей с помощью
image.SetPixel(i,j,color);
........
image.Save(ImagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);//Затем сохраняю:
```

Более никаких изменений не произвожу. Почему размер файла на выходе не соответствует файлу на входе? Высота/ширина не менялась. Изменялся только цвет. Каким образом сохранить измененную картинку в исходном размере?

Comment: сохраняли бы вы лучше в png ;)

Comment: Нужен именно BMP )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Размер меняется, потому что меняются параметры кодирования изображения (глубина цвета, качество или тп).
[Вот ссылка на параметры кодирования изображения при сохранении](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter.aspx)

Чтобы размер был тот же, вам необходимо использовать [эту перегрузку метода Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ytz20d80.aspx) и в параметрах указать [EncoderParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameters.aspx) такие же как в исходном изображении.

Comment: Спасибо! А как вытянуть EncoderParameters из исходного изображения не подскажите?

Comment: Понятия не имею, если честно.

Comment: там типа структура записывается в начале файла. Она в виде С++ но это можно преобразовать на С#. прочитать заголовок файла через FileStream

Comment: Наверняка в c# уже есть нечто подобное. Надо только найти. :)